# What is the difference between sales shipping and shipping

Tags: magento-enterprise, shipping

Under Reports - Orders.

What is the difference between the 'sales shipping' value and 'shipping' value?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As listed here: http://www.magenshop.com/magento-wiki/sales-reports-specifications.html

> - “Sales Shipping” — shipping part of the Sales Total (shipping total amount - shipping total canceled)
> - “Shipping”* — shipping part of the Revenue (shipping total invoiced - shipping total refunded)

Comment: I added the relevant information from the link as quote, so that the answer still has value, should the link go down.